# run Python script as a system command from terminal like "ls" in linux OS

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I have a python script which i want to run from terminal in linux without using "python" keyword in the beginning. 
For example my script name is helloworld.py which is accepting 2 arguments from terminal.
**I want to run this script as "helloworld" from terminal instead of "python helloworld.py"**

Comment: Next to `sys.argv` is the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module, which is the more comprehensive way of handling arguments.

Comment: I am not concerned about passing the argument. I know how to do that. I am concerned about running my python script directly from terminal in linux(helloworld) like a command(eg ls -l) with the name of the script not by using "python helloworld.py"

Comment: You want a hash-bang: put `#! /usr/bin/env python` as the first line of your script, and make the script executable: `chmod ugo+x script.py`.

Comment: ok but still with this i have to run the script like this "./script". I want to run it as system command like grep or ls

Comment: You don't need the `./` in front of the name if you set your `PATH` to include your current directory: `export PATH=$PATH:.` or similar.

Comment: @NishankSingla Evert is right.

Comment: Ok. 
Thanks @Evert. Will try this.

Answer (score 4):

To make the file an executable, rename and change the mode for the access permissions, e.g.:

```
$ mv helloworld.py helloworld
$ chmod +x helloworld
```

And edit the first line of the file be a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

There are at least three ways to run it from a shell:

1. Use something like `./helloworld` or `/path/to/helloworld`
2. Move it to a directory on your `PATH`, e.g. `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`
3. Modify `PATH` to add the directory, e.g. `export PATH=$PATH:/to/dir`

Comment: Dont forget to place it somewhere within PATH if you want to use it without the ./

Comment: after adding to path variable. It is running as helloworld.py and for removing .py also, you have to add "ln -s /path/to/helloworld.py /path/to/helloworld". Now I can run it as helloworld. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it :)

Comment: @NishankSingla You don't need a symlink, you can just rename the script: the .py extension is not necessary for anything, just convenience.

Comment: rename the script to what ? You mean to say save the python script without .py extension ?

Comment: @NishankSingla file extensions are just part of the name of the file, and don't have any significance on how it acts as a command executable. You can even add `.exe` if you want to mess with some folks.

Comment: Ok. But Without extension how OS will get to know what to use to run a file ?

Comment: @Mike Do i have to run the export command every time after rebooting the system ? I tried running the program again after system reboot but it said command not found and then when i again use the export command then it started working.

Comment: @NishankSingla usually folks add custom `export PATH` to their `~/.bashrc` profile to set their `PATH` each time they log in. And again, file extensions are not used by the OS, so you can use any arbitrary name.